# Recursive template function iterating over several template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I wrote a variadic template which is executing a functor `F`
 exactly `N` times and accumulating the result. Now I wonder how to make this template able to process a variable amount of index (template) parameters currently named `id` and in the desired functor `x, y, z`.

What I have in mind was a functor like below which is executed as if you call it three for loops. I also wonder whether it could be solved by argument lists.

```
struct 3DFunctor {
    template <int x, int y, int z>
    static int run() {
        return x*y*z;
    }
};
```

Desired behavior should be something like:

```
accum_for<3,3,3>::get<3DFunctor>();

3DFunctor::run<0,0,0>(/*args ...*/) +
3DFunctor::run<0,0,1>(/*args ...*/) +
3DFunctor::run<0,0,2>(/*args ...*/) +
3DFunctor::run<0,1,0>(/*args ...*/) +
3DFunctor::run<0,1,1>(/*args ...*/) +
3DFunctor::run<0,1,2>(/*args ...*/) +
// ..
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct F {
    template <int id>
    static int run(int val) {
        return id * val;
    }
};

template<unsigned int n>
struct accum1d_for {
    template <class Funct, class ... ArgTypes>
    static auto get(ArgTypes ... args) -> decltype(Funct::template run<0>(args ...)) {
        return (
            accum1d_for<n-1>::template get<Funct>(args ...) + 
            Funct::template run<n>(args ...)
        );
    }
};

template<>
struct accum1d_for<0> {
    template <class Funct, class ... ArgTypes>
    static auto get(ArgTypes ... args) -> decltype(Funct::template run<0>(args ...)) {
        return static_cast<decltype(Funct::template run<0>(args ...))>(0);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << accum1d_for<10>::get<F>(2.f) << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: Added desired behavior

Comment: tried a "using blah = " but got a compiler error. Not sure whether this works in function bodies.

Comment: Wich version of language? C++11, C++14 or C++17?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a C++14 solution (using `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence()`; if you need a C++11 solution should be simple create a substitute).

I've added `constexpr` to your `get()` so you can use it to initialize `constexpr` values.

And I've used `std::size_t` instead `int` because you wrote about "index", so it's a little simpler.

The example

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct Functor3D
 {
   template <std::size_t x, std::size_t y, std::size_t z>
   static constexpr std::size_t run ()
    { return x*y*z; }
 };

template <std::size_t ... topIs>
struct accum_for
 {
   private: 
      template <std::size_t ... Is>
      using IndS = std::index_sequence<Is...>;

      template <typename Func, std::size_t ... Is>
      static constexpr std::size_t h1 (IndS<Is...> const &)
       { return Func::template run<Is...>(); }

      template <typename Func, std::size_t ... I0s,
                std::size_t ... Ins, typename ... Ts>
      static constexpr std::size_t h1 (IndS<I0s...>, IndS<Ins...>,
                                       Ts const & ... ts)
       {
         using unused = int[];

         std::size_t ret { 0 };

         (void)unused { 0,
            ((void)(ret += h1<Func>(IndS<I0s..., Ins>{}, ts...)), 0)... };

         return ret;
       }

   public:
      template <typename Func>
      static constexpr std::size_t get () 
       { return h1<Func>(IndS<>{}, std::make_index_sequence<topIs>()...); }
 };

int main(void)
 {
   constexpr std::size_t val { accum_for<3U, 3U, 3U>::get<Functor3D>() };

   std::cout << val << std::endl;
 }
```

If you can use C++17, the generic version of the `h1()` helper function (the one with the `unused` array) can be simplified as follows

```
  template <typename Func, std::size_t ... I0s,
            std::size_t ... Ins, typename ... Ts>
  static constexpr std::size_t h1 (IndS<I0s...>, IndS<Ins...>,
                                   Ts const & ... ts)
   { return ( h1<Func>(IndS<I0s..., Ins>{}, ts...) + ... ); }
```

Comment: It seems to work but looks complicated. Can you help me to understand some expressions? a) using unused = int[]; is this an alias for an array?  b) Why do the array initializers {...} lack an = operator? c) Why is a void conversion necessary?

Comment: @dgrat - it's look complicated but what you ask isn't simple (but the c++17 version it's simpler); (a) yes: it's an alias for an array; it's used because you can't write `int [] { }` (without giving a name to the variable) but you can write `unused { }`; (b) it's called "uniform initialization", introduced starting from c++11; (c) there are two "void conversion"; the first one (`(void)unused`) isn't necessary but useful to avoid a warning of type "unused value" (or similar); the second one (`(void)(ret+=...`) it's necessary to avoid a bug in some versions of clang++

Answer (score 3):

With `std::index_sequence`, you may do

```
template <std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2, std::size_t N3>
struct accum_for
{
private:
    template <class Funct, std::size_t ... Is>
    static int get(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        int res = 0;
        using int_array = int[];
        static_cast<void>(int_array{0, (res += Funct::template run<Is / N3 / N2,
                                                                   (Is / N3) % N2,
                                                                   Is % N3>())...});
        return res;
    }


public:
    template <class Funct>
    static int get() {
        return get<Funct>(std::make_index_sequence<N1 * N2 * N3>());
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3f43cb9f7dac0c1)

Comment: Wonderful solution for 3 index (+1) but the OP ask for a solution "template able to process a variable amount of index (template) parameters"

Answer (score 1):

Given n tuples, generate their cross product (the tuple of one element from each, where every combination is covered).

Given a tuple of integral constants, invoke run with their values.

Given a value, generate a tuple of integral constants from 0 to n-1.

Given a tuple, execute a function object on each element.

3 and 1 defines the cube you want to run on.

Pass that cube to 4, together with a lambda that does 2.

While it woukd be amusing to write, not worth it to replace 9 lines of code.  None of the above operations are prewritten in std; I assume most metaprogramming libraries would have them implemented.  It would take less than 50 lines for each of the above steps to write from scratch using std (possibly much less).